# Why does update-notifier needs tons of additional packages to be installed?

Tags: updates, motd, update-notifier

I see some people have these `motd` scripts showing them information like:

```
23 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

I did some research and found out these are provided by a package called "update-notifier"

So I did a `sudo apt install update-notifier` and I got this:

[image]

Ugh... I mean.. I just want to know if I have updates or not. Do I need all of these ?

Was gonna have this on few small remote servers by the way. It's not a desktop machine where resources are unlimited, so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `update-notifier` package is for Desktop systems with a complete Desktop Environment (like Gnome). However, it's pretty clear from your output that you are running a headless server of some kind.

Adding any desktop or GUI application will, of course, drag in an entire desktop stack...which is exactly what your apt output indicates.

It's also important for you to know that the Message Of The Day (motd) package count at login is NOT up-to-date. It's generated once daily, stored at /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available, and quickly becomes stale. It is NOT recalculated at boot or login (doing so would delay boot or login for little gain)

Most admins that I know use Unattended Upgrades to quietly install security updates once each day in the background, and review non-security updates weekly or monthly.

Comment: Good explanation. I thought I could use some extra info at each login just to get a glance at system's health. Just like you said it's definitely not worth it for servers.